# Search is not filtering correctly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, filter

I'm having trouble, to perform the filter, when I search for a word, all the products in my database appear, could you give me a hand?

Part of my backend:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hc3J.png)

Part Front

```
import SearchInput from './SearchInput';
import api from '../../services/api';

export default function Example(){
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(text){
            api.get(`/product?filter[productName]=${text}`)
                .then((response) =>  {
                    const products = response.data;
                    setProduct(products);
                })
            
        }
    },[text]);

    return(
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Pesquisa de produtos</h1>
            <SearchInput value={text} 
                onChange={(search) => setText(search)}
            />
            {product &&  (
                <ul>
                    {product.map(product=>(
                        <li key={product.id}>
                            {product.productName}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
                
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Site view when searching:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tenh0.png)

Comment: for view filtering result, you can use conditional rendering when render `product` based on the value of `text`

Comment: Well it looks like your backend is just returning all the results in the database, it doesn't use the filter you send from the front end to only get desired records. Your backend should do that, otherwise what's the point of having a filter option on the endpoint

Comment: @Jayce444 So what happens, I use this part, to show me the list of products in the main part of the site, but I don't know if I need to create a separate async function just for filters.

Comment: @Ramayana3 I didn't clearly understand his way of saying how to render a product.